# Save object only if fields are not empty

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have a form where you can create 5 patients at once. The patient will be saved as long as the email field & test field are not blank, but the user could fill the first name and last name fields and the instance won't be saved without him knowing why. Unfortunately, If I put hibernate validation it will require to fill the 5 patient fields, but it might be that the user only wants to save 1 patient.

What I did, is an if statement like this :

```
for (Patient patient : form.getPatient()){
            if(!patient.getEmail().isBlank() && !patient.getTest().equals(null)){
                repository.save(patient);
            }
        }
```

I could actually add two other conditions to the if statement, like firstName and Lastname, but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance,

```
@Controller
public class PatientController {

        @Autowired
        PatientRepository repository;

        @GetMapping("/")
        public String patientsList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("patients", repository.findAll());
        return "patient-list";
         }

        @GetMapping("/create")
        public String CreateForm(Model model) {
        PatientCreation patientsForm = new PatientCreation();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            patientsForm.addPatient(new Patient());
        }

        model.addAttribute("form", patientsForm);
        //model.addAttribute("patients", repository.findAll());
        return "create-patient-form";
        }


        @PostMapping("/save")
        public String savePatients(@ModelAttribute PatientCreation form,  Model model) {
        for (Patient patient : form.getPatient()){
            if(!patient.getEmail().isBlank() && !patient.getTest().equals(null)){
                repository.save(patient);
            }
        }

        model.addAttribute("patients", repository.findAll());
        return "redirect:/";
    }

    }

    }
```

[Patients form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZNxY.png)

Comment: As object.isEmpty doesn't exist I was thinking about maybe creating a lambda to check if the object is blank. Thanks in advance for your solutions

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I found this :

```
  @PostMapping("/save")
    public String savePatients(@ModelAttribute PatientCreation form,  Model model) {
        List<Patient> filteredPatients = form.getPatient()
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(p -> !p.getTest().getDisplayValue().isBlank())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Patient p : filteredPatients){
            repository.save(p);
    }
```

I'd like know to find how I can add validation for the fields that are being effectively populated, without forcing the user to fill the 5 patients object. Only the ones he wants to fill if he only wants to fill one.